# Save or send by email google chrome web history and visited sites list?

Tags: google-chrome, api

I am trying to implement [quantifiedself](http://quantifiedself.com/) concept for my web-history. It was quit easy for most of the social networks with help of IFTTT. But currently I want to log and automatically send by email or convert into RSS all available information from **Google**: web search, web pages I visited, anything possible (except email).

I was digging the google web search and google chrome (the only browser I am using) - but I can't find any ready to use tool. It's definitely that google have all information - but how to access it? is there any central API for google web search and google chrome browser history?

(PS: I know that the google chrome save all history locally but it's not convenient, because I am using andorid devices, sometimes windows, mostly ubuntu. All information already stored centrally - so how to access it?)